# access time change for directive

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a webserver document root as `/var/www/html`, inside that I have a folder called `system`. If I access the url

> http://test.system.com/system/hello.img

in browser the access time of the `file(hello.img)` is changed but not the system folder. My requirement is when I access the file in a folder, the `folder access time` also has to be updated. I didn't find it in filesystem option. Your Help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Sugumar

Comment: It's not any kind of filesystem option. If the directory itself isn't accessed then its atime won't change.